# Styled Component Props in NextJS 12.2.5

Tags: next.js, styled-components

The NextJS documentation states support for Styled Components was added to SWC in v12.1.0.

I'm currently using NextJS v12.2.5 and Styled Component props don't work. However, the basic implementation of Styled Components without using props does work. Does NextJS support styled component props?

```js
// The follow has been added to next.config.js
    compiler: {
        styledComponents: true,
      },


//This does not work when 'warning' prop is passed to the component.

  const Wrapper = styled.div `
    background-color: ${props => props.warning ? 'red' : 'blue'}
    `
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a `.babelrc.js` file?

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    [
      "babel-plugin-styled-components",
      {
        minify: false,
        ssr: true,
        pure: true,
        displayName: true,
        preprocess: false,
      },
    ],
  ],
}
```